# circle button with image

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I am tryin to make a circle button with image, also i want to add seperator background them. I can create a circle button but i have no idea how to add image and separator on this.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Round_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#0dbe00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#c20586"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

What i want :

[image]

What i have :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
     <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button3"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/button4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And round_button:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="ring">
            <solid android:color="#0dbe00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="ring">
            <solid android:color="#c20586"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

> also i want to add seperator background them. I can create a circle
>   button but i have no idea how to add image and separator on this.

to add an image to the Button you can use `android:src`

to separate the items you could add a `View` between the buttons. E.g.

```
<View
  android:layout_width="5dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button4" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```